# Searching for a Solana community

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli, development

I'm a Solana developer and I'm having some problems with Anchor and deploying to the devnet, I'm looking for a Solana development community(Discord/Twitter etc..), do you have any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Anchor discord: https://discord.gg/NHHGSXAnXk

Solana Tech: https://discord.com/invite/solana

LamportDAO: https://twitter.com/LamportDAO

Solana Mobile: https://discord.gg/solanamobile

Solana Collective: https://discord.gg/solanacollective

Metaplex: https://discord.gg/metaplex

Solana Flutter: https://discord.gg/M2kakEAX

Helius: https://discord.gg/helius

Solana Hackathon: https://discord.gg/eHTzGK2B

Answer (score 0):

another good place to check would be with the mango market socials

https://twitter.com/mangomarkets

[discord.gg/8vs8uJJrcp](https://discord.gg/8vs8uJJrcp)

https://forum.mango.markets/

also the jito team and the firedancer team at jump as well

https://twitter.com/jito_sol

https://twitter.com/jump_firedancer

mango and jump and jito are often referred to as core contributors

in the solana ecosystem due to their client development efforts